# How to get good grip on NSMutableDictionary, NSEnumerator, NSMutableSet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, nsenumerator

I am little bit backward in knowledge on these three topics: `NSMutableDictionary`, `NSEnumerator`, `NSMutableSet`. When I want to use them, it feels very hard, even when I've gone through the developer documentation.

Is there any sample code to understand it clearly for all three topics?

Please help me.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to understand these depends on what your prior experience is. `NSDictionary` is exactly what it sounds like: a dictionary. What that means is that given a key (or a *headword*, as in a dictionary), you can look up a value (or *definition*):

For instance, this dictionary gives information about my dog:

```
KEY        VALUE
-------------------------------------------
@"name"       @"tucker"
@"species"    @"canis lupus familiaris"
@"favorite"   @"biscuits"
```

With a dictionary `dogInfo` containing that information, we could send `[dogInfo objectForKey:@"name"]` and expect to receive `@"tucker"`.

The difference between `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` is that the latter allows changes after initialization. This lets you do things like `[dogInfo setObject:@"fetch" forKey:@"game"]`. This is helpful for maintaining state, memoizing referentially transparent requests, etc.

`NSSet` is a way to have a bunch of objects, with a few important bits: there is no defined order to those objects, and there can only be one of each object (no duplicates). Use `NSSet` for when you need to contain unique, unordered objects. `NSMutableSet` is the variant of `NSSet` which allows for changes (such as adding or removing objects) after initialization.

`NSEnumerator` is a bit more complicated, but you usually won't need to deal with it unless you are writing your own libraries, are coding archaically, or are doing complex enumerations. Subclasses of `NSEnumerator` are used by collection classes, such as `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, and `NSSet`, to allow their objects to be enumerated. Usually, you'd just enumerate over them using a `foreach`-loop, since they all implement `<NSFastEnumeration>`. But sometimes, you'll want to do more specific things, like enumerate over the objects (instead of the keys) of a dictionary, or enumerate over an array in reverse. This is where instances of `NSEnumerator` (usually defined as properties on your collection objects) will become helpful.

#### Update

Justin in the comments pointed out that `NSEnumerator` conforms to `<NSFastEnumeration>`; that means, the chances are next-to-nothing that you'll need to know how to use an `NSEnumerator`; you can just do a `foreach` loop over the enumerator itself, like so:

```
for (id object in [dogDict objectEnumerator]) {
  // doing something with the object, disregarding its key
}
```

Comment: Finally, an answer analogizing `NSDictionary` to a real-life dictionary :)

Comment: Glad you like… :) I jumped the gun a bit when I submitted, but I've gone back and finished my explanation of `NSEnumerator`.

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling Even if you have to use an `NSEnumerator` object, they conform to `<NSFastEnumeration>` themselves, so there's even less reason to know how to use one.

Comment: @Madan, I think I've explained these sufficiently, and have interspersed some small code-bits. If you don't understand the basic concepts of unique-sets and dictionaries after my explanation, your problem isn't going to be solved by seeing sample-code. As for Cocoa enumerators, I recommend that you don't get hung up on that; should you ever need to use one, you'll probably understand it by then.